# Restructuring nested maps

Tags: c++, hash-map

I am in the process of making an assembler and one of the needed steps is actually getting the opcode from a table. However, the instruction set I'm working on has a handful of different addressing modes which give different opcodes. On top of that, even if you have the same mode the parameter size changes the opcode as well. This means to get an opcode I need to provide an instruction, an addressing mode, and a size. I also need to be able to get the average size for an addressing mode for setting an estimated size for another portion of my code.

My first solution was to make a large map to hold all the values. This has turned into a 200+ line triple-nested map. Something like this:

```
// <Instruction, <Addressing Mode, <Size, Opcode>>>
std::map<std::string, std::map<AddressMode, std::map<int, int>>> OpcodeTable = {
  {"ADC", {{Indirect_X, {{2, 0x61}}},
          {Stack, {{2, 0x63}}},
          {Direct, {{2, 0x65}, {3, 0x6D}, {4, 0x6F}}},
          {Indirect_Long, {{2, 0x67}}},
          {Immediate, {{2, 0x69}}},
          {Indirect_Y, {{2, 0x71}}},
          {Indirect, {{2, 0x72}}},
          {Stack_Y, {{2, 0x73}}},
          {Indexed_X, {{2, 0x75}, {3, 0x7D}, {4, 0x7F}}},
          {Indirect_Long_Y, {{2, 0x77}}},
          {Indexed_Y, {{3, 0x79}}}}},
   // and so on for every instruction
};
```

Currently I access this table through a function called `get_opcode` which hides the ugliness of navigating this map.

```
// Checks whether a given value exists in the table or not
bool has_opcode(std::string& instr, AddressMode& mode, int size)
{
  return (detail::OpcodeTable[instr].count(mode) == 1) &&
         (detail::OpcodeTable[instr][mode].count(size) == 1);
}

uint8_t get_opcode(std::string& instr, AddressMode& mode, int size)
{
  if (has_opcode(instr, mode, size))
  {
    return detail::OpcodeTable[instr][mode][size];
  }

  // If an invalid instruction is found, throw an exception with details on what it found.
  throw InvalidInstructionException(
          "Invalid instruction: " + instr +
          " with size " + util::to_string(size) +
          " and mode " + AddressModeString[mode] +
          " does not exist.");
}
```

I have seen ideas for using a pair as a key, and that helps slightly. It effectively turns into this, but I am not sure if this is a notable improvement.

```
std::map<std::pair<std::string, AddressMode>, std::map<int, int>> OpcodeTable = {
  {{"ADC", Indirect_X}, {{2, 0x61}}},
  {{"ADC", Stack}, {{2, 0x63}}},
  {{"ADC", Direct}, {{2, 0x65}, {3, 0x6D}, {4, 0x6F}}},
  {{"ADC", Indirect_Long}, {{2, 0x67}}},
  {{"ADC", Immediate}, {{2, 0x69}}},
  {{"ADC", Indirect_Y}, {{2, 0x71}}},
  {{"ADC", Indirect}, {{2, 0x72}}},
  {{"ADC", Stack_Y}, {{2, 0x73}}},
  {{"ADC", Indexed_X}, {{2, 0x75}, {3, 0x7D}, {4, 0x7F}}},
  {{"ADC", Indirect_Long_Y}, {{2, 0x77}}},
  {{"ADC", Indexed_Y}, {{3, 0x79}}},
  // and so on for every instruction
};
```

Is there any cleaner way to structure this data? I don't need to avoid maps entirely, but I feel like I might have gone overboard with this setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take your "pair" version to its logical conclusion:

```
using Mnemonic = std::string;
enum AddressMode { /* ... */ };
using Size = int;
using InstructionDescription = std::tuple<Mnemonic, AddressMode, Size>;
using Opcode = uint8_t;
std::map<InstructionDescription, Opcode> OpcodeTable = {
    {{"ADC", Indirect_X, 2},    0x61 },
    {{"ADC", Stack, 2},         0x63 },
    {{"ADC", Direct, 2},        0x65 },
    {{"ADC", Indirect_Long, 2}, 0x67 },
    {{"ADC", Immediate, 2},     0x69 },
    {{"ADC", Direct, 3},        0x6D },
    {{"ADC", Direct, 4},        0x6F },
    {{"ADC", Indirect_Y, 2},    0x71 },
    {{"ADC", Indirect, 2},      0x72 },
    {{"ADC", Stack_Y, 2},       0x73 },
    // ...
};
```

There will only be 256 rows in this table, so it's totally manageable.

Or, do what real assembler-writers do: read the instruction set specification to learn how the bits of the opcode correspond to the meaning of the instruction, and then turn that into a short mathematical formula [instead of a huge lookup table](http://lesswrong.com/lw/l9/artificial_addition/).

For example:

```
enum AddressMode : uint8_t {
    Indirect_X = 0x01,
    Stack = 0x03,
    Direct = 0x05,
    Indirect_Long = 0x07,
    Immediate = 0x09,
    Indirect_Y = 0x11,
    Indirect = 0x12,
    Stack_Y = 0x13,
    // ...
};

Opcode get_opcode(Mnemonic instr, AddressMode mode, Size size)
{
    if (instr == "ADC") {
        unsigned size_mask = (size == 2) ? 0 : (size == 3) ? 8 : 10;
        return 0x60 + int(mode) + size_mask;
    } else if // ...
}
```

> I'd think having to search all the instructions every time (up to 3 times per instruction based on optimizations) instead of an O(1) lookup seems like it may increase the time taken to assemble the code which may be over 100k lines in some tests, but I don't have any data to back that up.

Lookups in a `std::map` are *not* \$O(1)\$; they're \$O(\log n)\$ and involve a ton of pointer traversals. Doing the same \$O(\log n)\$ operations on a sorted array (which is going to be contiguous in memory, therefore [cache-friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699247/what-is-cache-friendly-code)) will be faster — probably even faster than using some actually "\$O(1)\$" (cough handwave cough) yet still cache-unfriendly container such as `std::unordered_map`.

Anyway, my second code example above is what you'll want to do if you really need the speed (which I'm sure you don't). Simple arithmetic operations will *always* be lightning-fast compared to *any* kind of container lookup. But at some point, probably long before any of this starts mattering, the *real* performance bottleneck will be in how fast you can read that 100K of assembly code off the filesystem and how fast you can write the machine code back out. The code that turns mnemonics into opcodes isn't the bottleneck; I guarantee it.

Comment: The second example looks pretty promising. Another assembler that works on the same instruction set does something similar, although the code for that will make your eyes bleed. As for the O(1) thing, I figured out I was confusing it with unordered_map, but then I found out that could still take O(n) in worst case. Neither look as promising as I'd previously hoped. Thanks for covering that as well.

Comment: Let me reinforce what Quux is saying here. There's a significant cost to traversing the pointer tree that `std::map` uses (not least of which is that it's cache-unfriendly). But, the cost of computing the hash function of `std::unordered_map` might be still higher (especially if it has to resolve collisions), so you might actually see a *decrease* in performance by switching to the O(1) algorithm. Don't fixate on the order of growth; you have to test for your actual use case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need `map`s at all. (They chew up a lot of memory, and don't seem particularly cache-friendly, at least the implementations I've tried)

Just make a `struct opcode` or `class opcode` with members instruction, address mode, size, and opcode. Make sure to overload the comparison operators for each opcode.

Instead of a giant nested map, the `OpcodeTable` will be a `std::array` or `std::vector` of those `struct`s in sorted order.

Then use `std::binary_search()` (from `#include <algorithm>`) to find your desired opcode.

Or, if you still want to use a `std::map`, make the `struct` or `class` for just the key fields, and the value of the `map` is the hex opcode. Upside: the code is easier to read. Downside: inefficient memory and cache usage.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have thought of a class solution before, but I preferred the maps. I don't think there's enough benefit in making classes that store the data since it makes it cumbersome to access and search efficiently. I'd think having to search all the instructions every time (up to 3 times per instruction based on optimizations) instead of an O(1) lookup seems like it may increase the time taken to assemble the code which may be over 100k lines in some tests, but I don't have any data to back that up. Second idea works, but I think it would end up being a pair like my final code.

Comment: `std::map` is O(lg n) because it's implemented as a binary tree so that it can be traversed in sorted order . If you want amortized O(1) you need to use `std::unordered_map` which is amortized O(1), though with higher coefficients. What searching do you need to do besides the lookup?

Comment: @ozdrgnaDiies: map doesn't have O(1) lookup, but O(log(n)), which is also provided by `std::binary_search` - maybe you are mixing that up with unordered_map, which is usually implemented as a hash_table. `std:.map` is usually one of the least efficent ways to implement a static lookup table (depending on the exact usage pattern of course).